# How to get results array data after update on mongodb in node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Below is my code

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongodbClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

MongodbClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err, db) {
    if(!err){
        console.log("We are connected!!");
    }

    var contact = db.collection('contact');

    contact.update({name: "Fred"}, {$set: {tel:'09088oooxxaa'}}, function(err,r) {
       if(err){
           console.log("Update err");
       }
       else{
           console.log('Update success');
           console.log(r.name);
       }
   });

   contact.find({name: "Fred"}).toArray(function(err, results) {
       console.log(results[0]);
   });
});
```

I can get the result array by using find() method in the end of this code.

However, I would like to know is any way I can get same results array in update function code by callback?

I tried to worte "console.log(r.name) in update code but show undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do a [`findAndModify`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify) so you don't need to do the find after the update because it returns the updated item too:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongodbClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

MongodbClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err, db) {
    if(!err){
        console.log("We are connected!!");
    }

    var contact = db.collection('contact');

    contact.findAndModify({name: "Fred"}, {$set: {tel:'09088oooxxaa'}}, function(err,r) {
       // r now contains the entire item updated
       if(err){
           console.log("Update err");
       }
       else{
           console.log('Update success');
           console.log(r.name);
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.So I can not use "r" in update callback when use update not findAndModify?

Comment: Yes you can't use it with an `update` command because it returns only the number of row updated not the items.

Comment: THanks. I though It will return the updated items also.Did you know where I can find these information which is what data it will return?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the `find` oepration inside the callback to `update`. The way you do it, your find operation fires prior to update.

```
var contact = db.collection('contact');

contact.update({name: "Fred"}, {$set: {tel:'09088oooxxaa'}}, function(err,r) {
   if(err) {
       console.log("Update err");
   }
   else {
       console.log('Update success');
       contact.find({name: "Fred"}).toArray(function(err, results) {
           console.log(results[0]);
       });
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's in the scope of the callback